# Choppy equations with tex4ht

Tags: math-mode, tex4ht

I am using MikTeX with Windows 7. I have installed `tex4ht` using the package manager. The conversion of formulae are not ideal. Some formulae seem a bit choppy while others seem very horrible.

Example of Choppy-looking formula.

[image]

Example of horrible-looking formula.

[image]

and

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

---

## Updated question

After the [suggestion of michal.h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359059/choppy-equations-with-tex4ht/359065#359065), the output looked a little bit better.

[image]

However the inline formulae needs a bit improvements.
For example

[image]

and

[image]

Some \begin{array} equations also needs improvements.

for example - Look at the minus sign and size of u.
[image]

I would like to point out in order to write the derivatives I am using a

> \newcommand{\Dn}[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N82hp.png){\frac{\text{d}^#1 #2}{\text{d}#3^{#1}}}  % for n-th derivative

I don't know if this should make any difference or not.

This is the link to [my code](https://codedump.io/share/ewV9GPrkgUHv/1) which was requested by Sebastiano.

Comment: Can you add your code `*.tex`, please?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the [available options](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) (`MathML`, `Other Options`).

Comment: just use svg for math and everything will be just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that Miktex haven't updated the last fixes regarding default quality of images in `tex4ht`. It uses `dvipng` for the conversion now, and the quality got much better. There are also other alternatives, such as to use vector `SVG` images, or to use `MathML` with `Mathjax` library for rendering.

You can easily use the better methods in `Miktex` as well, using `make4ht` build files. Save the following code as `mybuild.mk4`:

```
Make:image("png$","dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -D151  -o     ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:image("svg$","dvisvgm -n -p ${page} -c 1.4,1.4 -s ${source} > ${output}")
```

You can compile your file using

```
make4ht -ue mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

For the following nonsensical math sample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left(-\frac{{h}^{2}}{2m}\delta-\frac{{e}^{2}}{4\pi} \right) = \theta
\]
\end{document}
```

You will get the following `png` picture:

[image]

To get the `svg` image, you need to use small configuration file, `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

It requires the output format for the pictures to be the `svg` format. 
You can request the config file in the compilation using

```
make4ht -ue mybuild.mk4 -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

And this is the result. Note that it is blurred because it is screenshot from the browser, Stackexchange doesn't support `SVG` image upload. It looks better in the reality:

[image]

The last possibility is to use `MathML` with `MathJax`. Use the following config file, `mathjax.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
   </script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

compile the document using

```
make4ht -uc mathjax.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can try also other options for `MathJax` output, see `MML_SVG` and `MML_HTMLorMML` in the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html). You can put those options in the configuration file after `MathJax.js?config=`. I think the `MML_CMATH` is preferred nowadays, but the other options may work better for you.