# TeX4ht issue with chrome

Tags: tex4ht

Consider the following very simple LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \( z=e^{x^{2}+y^{2}} \)
\end{document}
```

Run it through TeX4ht using the command `make4ht -c config.cfg` where `config.cfg` is the configuration file

```
% We are generating HTML + MathML code
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

% Output HTML5 doctype instead of the default for HTML4
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!doctype html>\Hnewline}}

% Custom page opening
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

On firefox and safari this produces the expected output with a web page displaying

[image]

Unfortunately, on chrome this display incorrectly as:

[image]

That is, superscripts (and subscripts) are not displaying properly. I suspect that this is a mathml problem, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You requests `mathml` conversion with

```
 \Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
```

It is generally a good thing, because `tex4ht` uses images for math otherwise and it doesn't look really great. The problem is that not all browsers support `mathml` correctly (in fact none of them), or, as is the Chrome's case, they don't support it all. Fortunately, we can use `MathJax` library to fix these browser issues.

Also note, that `tex4ht` has basic support for `HTML5` now, so you can simplify your config file to look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,html5}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
   </script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

the `html5` support doesn't support `lang` attribute in `html` element, so we still need to configure `HTML` hooks.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am being stupid: I identified `mathml` as being the problem, so all that needs to be done is to remove `mathml` from the config file:

```
% We are generating HTML + MathML code
\Preamble{xhtml}

% Output HTML5 doctype instead of the default for HTML4
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!doctype html>\Hnewline}}

% Custom page opening
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: you can also use `MathJax` to display `mathml`,  see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359065/2891 for example

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks. This is a much better approach that mine. You should post and I"ll delete this.

Comment: OK, I provided new answer