# More TeX4ht issues with chrome and safari

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, xhtml

Take the following simple latex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

  $\overrightarrow{AB}$

  $|\mathbf{v}|$

  $e^{x^2+y^2}$

  $\{ x\in\R | x<0 \}$

  \begin{align*}
      f & = 1+2+3+4+\dots+n\\
        & = \binom{n+1}2
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

and run it through tex4ht/make4ht using the configuration file from
[TeX4ht issue with chrome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359951/tex4ht-issue-with-chrome/359962?noredirect=1#comment887127_359962)

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,html5}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
   </script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

(for example, use `make4ht -u -c file.cfg file.tex`). On firefox, safari and chrome this produces a web page with errors that look something like

[image]

The problem is with the mathjax settings. If, instead, I change the configuration file to use

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"
       src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_CHTML">
       </script>\Hnewline}}
```

then this page displays correctly on firefox but superscripts and subscripts, for example, do not display correctly on chrome and everything is pear-shaped on safari:

[image]

This shows how this web page produced by tex4ht displays on firefox, chrome and safari, respectively.

I have tried all of the mathjax settings given on http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html, as well as trying to configure mathjax directly using `MathJax.Hub.Config`, but I cannot find a way to get these examples to work. Firefox displays this page well with several of the mathjax configurations, chrome does OK with some and safari is not happy at all.

I have also tried using Michal's `mathjax-latex-4ht` package, described in [Converting latex to html using exsheets, and keeping equations as latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265815/converting-latex-to-html-using-exsheets-and-keeping-equations-as-latex/265916#265916). This is almost perfect except that it doesn't cope with the `\R` macro in my MWE:

[image]

Is there a way to configure tex4ht and mathjax to play well with this example on all browsers? Annoyingly, pandoc seems to produce sensible output here but in my real application I have some significant post-processing to do, which is possible using tex4ht and I am not sure if this can be done starting with pandoc.

Comment: Why the down vote? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by bug in configuration for `\mathbf` command:

```
\Configure{mathbf}%
 {\bgroup \Tg<\a:mathml mi mathvariant="bold">\PauseMathClass}%
  {\Tg</\a:mathml mi>\egroup }%
```

`tex4ht` automatically add markup around math variables and operators, but this is disabled by `\PauseMathClass` command in this configuration, because the markup is added explicitly in this case. The automatic markup must be turned on after end of `\mathbf`, otherwise it will result in invalid markup. Because your second math example contains `\mathbf`, all following examples contain invalid markup. We need to use `\EndPauseMathClass` command to turn markup on again.

I will fix this issue in `tex4ht` sources, but it will take some time before the fix goes to TeXLive, so you can use the following configuration in the meantime.

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,html5}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
   </script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Michal! I am amazed how quickly you find these things and fix them. Once again I am in your debt. I'll be in Praha for a few months towards the end of the year. More than happy to buy you a beer.

Comment: @Andrew it wasn't so hard to localize the bug, I introduced it to the sources not so long ago :D It would be nice to see you, there are not so many TeXies around me (much more in Brno than in Prague)