# mathdisplay in tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

i've read this question [Choppy equations with tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359059/choppy-equations-with-tex4ht/359065#359065) and currently im displaying math as png pictures with the mybuild.mk4 file

```
Make:image("png$","dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -D151  -o     ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:image("svg$","dvisvgm -n -p ${page} -c 1.4,1.4 -s ${source} > ${output}")
```

and compiling with

```
tex4ebook -c config.cfg -f epub3 -e mybuild.mk4 "%N%T"
```

but apparently this setup only works for the equation command in latex, not for align. Here's an example:

[image]

top is align, bottom equation. The equations are not centered and the baselines seem to get messed up. Furthermore, if the equation gets too long, instead of a linebreak or downscaling the label disappears

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{x}=\frac{1}{E}\cdot [\sigma_{x}-\upsilon \cdot(\sigma_{y} + \sigma_{z})] +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_{x}=\frac{1}{E}\cdot [\sigma_{x}-\upsilon \cdot(\sigma_{y} + \sigma_{z})]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make it work with align? Unfortunately i already have a lot of align environments in my latex file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the whole contents of align and equation environments to pictures. It is supported out of the box using `pic-align` option for align, for equation you must use simple configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align}
\ConfigureEnv{equation}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="equation">}\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{div.align,div.equation{text-align:right;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration will insert equation as a picture inside `<div class="equation">`. Css is then used to align both environments to the right.

This is a result:

[image]